# How to get ASCII value of a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I get the ascii value of the string which I enter in the text field? I also want to check if the alphabet which I type is lower case, upper case, comma or space. The function should return YES or NO.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

//    if (string.) {
//        <#statements#>
//    }

        [self performSelector:@selector(delayCall) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];


    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to help you.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


    char cStr = [string characterAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%d",(int)cStr);


    return YES;

}
```

Comment: This will truncate characters that don't fit in a byte. `characterAtIndex` returns `unichar`. Also, the cast to int is superfluous, since `NSLog()` is variadic, and type promotion takes effect.

Comment: ya It will filter only a char and return its ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

```
//char to int ASCII-code
char c = 'b';
int asCode = (int)c;

//int to char
int i = 66; // B
c = (char)i;
```

Answer (score 1):

first extract the character from string and then assign it to an integer variable. 
Now this var will contain the ascii value of the input char.

to check for its type check the ascii range
let x be the variable containing the ascii value then

if( x>64 && x<91)
then print "Capital char"
else if(x>96 and x<123)
then print "Small char"
and so on
for comma x==44
for space x==32

to get char from string 
char c=String(index_pos);